Creating an angular module lib with NX
I am creating a monorepo using the architecture of Shell, Feature, Ui, Util, Data. All are self-explantory. I am using the idea of 'Journeys' so each shell is an entry point into a journey e.g I am creating a fifa leaderboard journey where friends can create games, track scores between us etc.

Shell - Entry Point that my app with use and lazy load routes/features.
Feature - A smart library which will contain features such as 'Create Game' etc
UI - Dumb Components
Data - Api/Service Calls
Util - models/interfaces etc.

Using this architecture and using the shell as the entry point, I can restrict what components are exported, can be used externally etc and mainly in my apps to be lazy loaded.
I am struggling to create a module library with nx/angular. I cant find any docs but ideally my app.routes.ts would use the shell to create routes like:
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'fifa-league',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('.libs/fifa-league/fifa-league.module').then(
        (m) => m.FifaLeagueModule
      ),
  },
];

Or do I even need a shell module?


The feature-shell approach is not bad. You can use shell to orchestrate your route.  It’s directly connected with the domain-level concept of your app.
